# How to manipulate paragraph tag with jQuery in foreach block in MVC view

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using [jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ek4k.png) to change the value of a paragraph tag as a user checks a checkbox, problem I am facing is when the user checks a checkbox only the paragraph tag in the first record changes and the others do nothing

MVC View code as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="tabcolumn-container" style="height: 90px; border: 1px solid grey">

    <div class="tabcolumn30 frame" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <div style="height: 35px; background-color: grey;">
            <p style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold">@item.group_category</p>
        </div>
        <span class="helper">

            <img src="~/images/@item.image_path" />

        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tabcolumn50">

        <div style="height: 40px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-left: 1px solid grey; border-right: 1px solid grey">
            <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;100kms per day&emsp;&emsp;<input id="defaultOpen" type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="R @item.standard_100 per day" />&emsp;Standard Cover&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="R @item.super_100 per day" />&emsp;Upgrade to Super Cover</p>
        </div>

        <div style="height: 40px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-left: 1px solid grey; border-right: 1px solid grey">
            <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;200kms per day&emsp;&emsp;<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="R @item.standard_200 per day" />&emsp;Standard Cover&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="R @item.super_200 per day" />&emsp;Upgrade to Super Cover</p>
        </div>

        <div style="height: 40px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-left: 1px solid grey; border-right: 1px solid grey">
            <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;400kms per day&emsp;&emsp;<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="R @item.standard_400 per day" />&emsp;Standard Cover&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="R @item.super_400 per day" />&emsp;Upgrade to Super Cover</p>
        </div>

        <div style="height: 55px; display: table; border-left: 1px solid grey; background-color: grey; width: 569px; border-right: 1px solid grey">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tabcolumn20" style="height: 160px">
        <p style="font-size: 15px; text-align: center">Pick-up location: In Branch</p>
        <p style="font-size: 15px; text-align: center">Fuel Policy: Full to Full</p>
        <p style="padding-left: 50px; font-size: 23px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 24px" id="result">R @ViewBag.stand_100 per day</p>
        <input type="button" value="Book Now!" style="height: 56px; background-color: yellow; width: 227.66px; border-style: none"/>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
}
```

JQuery code as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slectOne').on('change', function () {
            $('.slectOne').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            $('#result').html($(this).data("id"));
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                $('#result').html($(this).data("id"));
            else
                $('#result').html('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Screenshot as follows:

[Screenshot01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ek4k.png)

As you can see from the screenshot all checkboxes are grouped together. How can I create a new group so that each record has its own grouping and does not share the checkboxes with other records, and how to allow those checkboxes to activate/manipulate its own paragraph tag and not just the 1st records paragraph tag?

Much appreciated in advance for your help

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html (and `$('#result').html(...)` will only ever select the first one. Use class names instead.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i believe you're mistaking `data-id` with `id` on this one. Nowhere in the script `id` attributes are used.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, Look at the code carefully - OP has `<p ... id="result">` inside a loop and is using `$('#result').html(...)` (which selects only the first `<p>` with `id-"result:`

Comment: I haven't noticed the `foreach`. My bad. You are correct. Code performs correctly but always outputs to `#result`, in first occurence. You should wrap it as answer.

Comment: Is there a way to assign a generated value to id? so for each record it holds a different id? Sorry I am fairly new to jQuery, Still researching and learning

Comment: Just use a `class` instead of an `id` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please explain further? I dont understand how a class can be used in this case to replace the ID

Comment: `<p ... class="result">` and `$('.result').html(...)`

Comment: LeevenPersad, I've added an answer wrapping up what @Stephen is pointing out, adding in a suggestion of my own for improving your code.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `id="result"` from your razor `foreach` with `class="result"` and change your jQuery to:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slectOne').on('change', function () {
        $('.slectOne').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        let result = $('.result', $(this).closest('.tabcolumn-container'));
        result.html($(this).is(":checked") ? $(this).data("id") : '');
    });
});
```

While at it, you might also remove `id="defaultOpen"` from the loop (duplicate `id`s are invalid in HTML) and, you might also want to remove all the inline `style`s and use classes to style the elements. It would make your code a lot cleaner and easier to maintain.

---

Ref: *" Sorry I am fairly new to jQuery"*:
**This has nothing to do with jQuery**. It's plain ol' HTML. In HTML, duplicate ids are **invalid**.

`id` based selection method in DOM

```
.getElementById('#someId')
```

only returns the first element with `id="someId"`, completely ignoring subsequent ones.
**`id`** of elements are supposed to be unique in DOM and they are the fastest way to select an element.

```html
<div id="foo">bar...</div>
<div id="foo">...tender => Only first item with same id is targeted. </div>
<script>
   document.getElementById("foo").style.color = 'red';
</script>
```

When you need to work with collection of DOM elements, you should use `class` attributes, which have been designed specifically for this purpose (to assign styles and/or behavior to each element with that `class`).

Even though illegal, technically, there is a possibility to run through multiple elements sharing the same `id`, using `querySelectorAll`:

```
 document.querySelectorAll("#someId").forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red');
```

But it doesn't make having same `id` more than once in DOM legal. Let's just say the above method works so you could programatically select all illegal elements and change their `id`s to unique ones, making your markup valid.

Comment: Thanks a million! Not only did your solution work, but it also gave me a better understanding of things